# Share session/cookie between subdomains for Play 2.X

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, session-cookies

I only can find Play 1.x has this setting. How to set this in Play 2.X?

http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/configuration

**application.defaultCookieDomain**

> Enables session/cookie sharing between subdomains. For example, to
>   make cookies valid for all domains ending with ‘.example.com’, e.g.
>   foo.example.com and bar.example.com:
>
> application.defaultCookieDomain=.example.com Default: a cookie is only
>   valid for a specific domain.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There was change for that problem [pulled into `Play 2.1`](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/pull/384/commits) but unfortunately it wasn't backported to `2.0.x`.

That means, that since Play 2.1 you can use in conf:

```
session.domain=".mydomain.com"
```

For `2.0.x` you need to patch the sources yourself.

Answer (score 15):

In play 2.4, `session.domain` has been deprecated. You should now use: `play.http.session.domain`